# Legal Issues of publishing a book on software?

Tags: copyright, fair-use

Not sure if this is the right place, but I'd like to know the process on how to  publish a book on Software that I didn't produce.  I can get the book printed, bound, and put on the market, but worried about legal issues with software.

For example, there are plenty of books written on how to use Excel, SQL Server, Windows, and they include screenshots from their respective software.

Let's say I wanted to publish a book on Windows 10 and sell publicly with an ISBN (barcode), is this legal?  I own a legal copy of the software with valid licenses, so I don't see why not.  Do I need to get written permission from Microsoft to use screenshots from their software?

Can I reference a solution on SuperUser in a book?  I'm all about giving credit, but not sure how to do this properly.

What about proprietary Enterprise software that I purchased?

As of right now, I just have the book printed with coil binding, and selling it without an ISBN on the side.

Comment: When you say, "how to publish a book on Software that I didn't produce", does "didn't produce" refer to the software or the book?  You can write a book about anything you want; you don't need to have produced the product you're writing about.  Most existing books are examples of that.  How to properly attribute, and the extent to which you can lift other people's work, are finer points that aren't a one-paragraph answer.